# overriding the entire class possible in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a class defined like this:

`baseException.ts`

```
/**
 * Override the default Error.
 *
 * @class Error
 * @extends {Error}
 */
class Error {
  /**
   * @type {string}
   * @memberof Error
   */
  message: string;

  /**
   * @type {boolean}
   * @memberof Error
   */
  isCustom: boolean;

  /**
   * @type {number}
   * @memberof Error
   */
  statusCode: number;

  /**
   * @param {string} message
   * @param {number} statusCode
   * @memberof Error
   */
  constructor(message: string, statusCode: number) {
    this.isCustom = true;
    this.message = message;
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
  }
}
```

All the rest of the code derive from this base class such as:
`import Error from baseException`
`ForbiddenError extends Error`
and we use this without error:

`throw new ForbiddenError`

But, why doesn't the base class Error do something like:

`class Error extends Error`  , there's no extend keyword, so how's it getting the behaviour of the base class?

Comment: did you mean the javascript `Error` class?

Comment: @Nullable , yes(or typescript Error class I suppose, since I'm using that). This class is somehow shadowing the default class but, also inheriting it's properties which I what I see when I use the `throw new Error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `throw` statement throws a user-defined exception.

When you throw an exception, `expression` specifies the value of the exception. Each of the following throws an exception:

```js
throw 'Error2'; // generates an exception with a string value
throw 42;       // generates an exception with the value 42
throw true;     // generates an exception with the value true
throw new Error('Required');  // generates an error object with the message of Required
```

So you can throw everything, and you do not need to have to extends the `Error` class.

The comments are document comments, yeah, but are still comments, so they do not interfere with the compiler.